# Nested 3 Tier LINQ Query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have multiple Person objects that each may contain 0 or more Email objects. I need to perform a search for a Person against a Collections of Persons and find records where an email addresses contained in Person also exists in any of the in the collection of Person records. I can then take action to merge these records

Summarised class structure below:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Email> Emails { get; set; }
}


public class Email
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Address{ get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
}
```

I need to find a List and find people with the same email address. However, I cant figure out how to construct a LINQ query that matches a Person and loops through a Collection of Person obejcts and compares email addresses?

Ideally this would be a lambda, but would love to know the step by step process for creating it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can project people to sequence of Email-Person pairs and group these sequence by email address. In this case each group will have people which share same email address (key of group):

```
people.SelectMany(p => p.Emails.Select(e => new { e.Address, Person = p }))
      .GroupBy(x => x.Address)
      .Select(g => new { Address = g.Key, People = g.Select(x => x.Person) })
```

Query syntax:

```
from p in people
from e in p.Emails
select new { e.Address, Person = p } into x
group x by x.Address into g
select new {
   Address = g.Key,
   People = g.Select(x => x.Person)
}
```

NOTE: If you need whole email to be unique, then override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods of `Email` in order to compare instances of this class by values of its fields instead of by reference (or make sure you are share same instances of email between different people).

Comment: likely that @ISAIMobile needs only unique Addresses not Email records, so there will be no need to override equals/hash

Comment: ie `people.SelectMany(p => p.Emails.Select(e => new { Email = e.Address, Person = p.Id })).GroupBy(x => x.Email)`

Comment: Well I guess he does not have to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` Comparing `Address` should be enough since two people can't have same address

Comment: @vittore yep, thanks. Already updated answer (it was not clear to me from question, that only Address field matters)